# Downvoted questions on Meta with a non-negative scored answer on them should no longer be hidden from the main page

Tags: feature-request, meta, homepage

A simple suggestion:

- If a question has one or more answers,
- **and** one of the answers is not negatively scored (with a minimum of two votes),

...then the post should still be shown on the main page irrespective of the question's score.

For support questions, we have a penchant of downvoting them when they're not really all that...clear, or useful, or are points to vent on.  However, if there is value to be had in a support question, then someone would post an answer, and that answer would likely be upvoted.

The minimum two votes' thing is there to prevent an OP from disagreeing with the stated support path, yet having received an otherwise valuable answer.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332465/332043

Comment: I've tagged this [homepage] for now although strictly speaking the tag isn't meant for the meta homepage. Do we care or can we handle this probably one-of odd one out?

Comment: I don't really see a need for filtering out questions on meta in any case, meta voting is so random... often the ones that are heavily downvoted are exactly the ones you want to see. So I always use the all question view rather than the homepage.

Comment: I don't think [support] is a special case here at all, really. High-score answers on downvoted [discussion] or [feature-request] questions can also have value. Indeed, besides the final paragraph, you could literally just find and replace the word "support" with "discussion" or "feature request" in this question and, as far as I can tell, it would be no less true than it is now. Why restrict this change to [support]?

Comment: @MarkAmery: It's a conversation starter. I'm okay with expanding it to any tag.

Comment: @rene: Not too bothered with the tag choice.

Comment: If implemented, this proposal would increase the number of gold reversal badges awarded.

Comment: @user000001:  [No it wouldn't](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/06/18/adios-to-unfriendly-badges-ahoy-lifejacket-and-lifeboat/)

Comment: I think all tags is good. Users want support, but mis-tag as discussion.